# How to select an option that was added to a select

Tags: jquery

I wrote a little function to set the options to a select that I pass into the function with up to three options depending upon the second function parameter. I am using jquery. I can't seem to get an option's selected property to work at all. If there is only a single variable (aka, "X") then I want to select it since it is the only option. I have tried a number of things including the additional arguments on the Option object. For some reason this is not working.

```
function setAxisSelect(select, numVariableTransitions) {
    $(select).find('option').remove();
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 2)
        $(select).append(new Option('', ''));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 1) 
        $(select).append(new Option('X', 'x'));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 2)
        $(select).append(new Option('Y', 'y'));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 3)
        $(select).append(new Option('Z', 'z'));

    if (numVariableTransitions === 1)
        $(select).children("option[value='x']").prop('selected', true); // THis is not working

    if (numVariableTransitions === 1)
        $(select).val('x'); // This also doesn't work, LOL
}
```

I've tried $(select).find('option') and I tried .attr and .prop both. I know .prop is the better way.

This is also not working. There is something odd going wrong here.

```
function setAxisSelect(select, numVariableTransitions) {
    $(select).find('option').remove();
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 2)
        $(select).append(new Option('', '', false, false));
    if (numVariableTransitions === 1) 
        $(select).append(new Option('X', 'x', true, true));
    else if (numVariableTransitions >= 1)
        $(select).append(new Option('X', 'x', false, false));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 2)
        $(select).append(new Option('Y', 'y', false, false));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 3)
        $(select).append(new Option('Z', 'z', false, false));
}
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
_.forEach(variants, function (val, idx) {
     //some other not related stuff...
    setAxisSelect($('#variantAxis' + (idx + 1)), variants.length);
});
```

=========UPDATE==========
Looking at the source pane, i can see that jquery is added in the selected property on the X option just as I want. So, it's working in the code but the actual UI doesn't reflect that. Here is a screenshot of it. You can see the X option is selected but not actually rendering that way in browser pane.

[image]

Comment: `$(select).val('x')`. Although what you have should work. If you have issues witht hat we need to see a working example in order to debug it fully

Comment: I tried that first before anything else and that didn't work. The options are getting added correctly. I am totally mystified as to why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter from the `Option()` method is `defaultSelected`, and the fourth one is `selected` you can achieve that by doing this. But the problem here in your implementation is that you can parameterize which option gets selected when you are rendering. You need to change the function if you want in this case option `x` to be selected by default.

```js
function setAxisSelect(select, numVariableTransitions) {
    $(select).find('option').remove();
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 2)
        $(select).append(new Option('', '', false, false));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 1) 
        $(select).append(new Option('X', 'x', false, false));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 2)
        $(select).append(new Option('Y', 'y', true, true));
    if (numVariableTransitions >= 3)
        $(select).append(new Option('Z', 'z', false, false));
}
setAxisSelect('.mySelect', 4)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mySelect">
  <option>initial</option>
</select>
```

Comment: SO I have to use the defaultSelected and selected parameters on the Option object for all options or it won't work? I am confused about why I can't just set the selected property on the x option directly. I only want x selected by default if there is only a single option in the select, so when numVariableTransitions=1.

Comment: I added another example, based on your answer, that is also not working for me. But, I agree that it should work. There is something else at hand here that we are not seeing.

Comment: With what parameters are you calling the function? `setAxisSelect( ?, ? )`

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have made that clear. I'll add that to the question above. It's:  setAxisSelect($('#variantAxis' + (idx + 1)), variants.length);

Comment: variants.length is 1, 2, or 3

Comment: Why do you need the `forEach`? Just call `setAxisSelect('#variantAxis', variants.length)`, if the variants.length is dynamic.

Comment: Okay this is interesting. If I look in the source, the "selected" property is in fact being added correctly. So, the logic is working, but it doesn't actually show the option as selected in the browser pane. I will upload a pic.